# Replace the word between 2nd underscore and 3rd underscore

Tags: java

What is the best way to replace the string/word between 2nd underscore and 3rd underscore?
This is my usual string `X Services alba_tango_2021H1_[ten]`
And I want to replace `2021H1` with `test`.
`X Services alba_tango_test_[ten]`
I tried different ways but they don't work and I don't want to divide the string into different arrays, as I think is a very long way.

Comment: Either with `String.split()` or regular expressions.

Comment: I tried but I can't make it work, can you please sir provide me an example, and besides split I want to replace it.

Comment: @user16320675 yeah it makes sense but do check that I replace the string between second and third underscore

Comment: @gjonte just split on the underscore, replace the xth element of the resulting array, and use String concatenation to put it back together

Comment: Not an expert in regex, but try something like `String output = input.replaceAll("([^_]*_[^_]*_)([^_]*)(_.*)","$1test$3");`

Comment: @Eritrean actually there is no need for the second group... almost the same i would have done(I would have used `*+` instead of `*`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_indexof.asp) and specify the `fromIndex` parameter, this way you can easily find out the first, the second and the third occurrence of underscore. But just make sure that the assumption that your `String` has 3 underscores is correct. In the example below:

- `input` is the index you want to work with
- `replacement` is whatever you want to place between the second and third underscore
- `output` is the `String` you need

```
int firstUnderscore = input.indexOf("_");
int secondUnderscore = input.indexOf("_", firstUnderscore + 1);
int thirdUnderscore = input.indexOf("_", secondUnderscore + 1);
String output = input.substring(0, firstUnderscore + 1) + replacement + input.substring(thirdUnderscore);
```

EDIT

The code above assumes that we know for sure that there are at least 3 underscores. If there is any possibility that the `String` would contain less than 3 underscores, then you will always need to check whether `indexOf()` returns a value that's greater or equal than 0, which means that there was a valid index for the searched term, in other words, it means that the searched term was found.

In my answer I avoided this check because the question seemed to suggest that we have a format that we can rely on, so I decided to rely on this format rather than complicate the answer with `indexOf` checks. If we cannot rely on this format, then we can change the code to something like

```
String output = input;
int firstUnderscore = input.indexOf("_");
if (firstUnderscore >= 0) {
    int secondUnderscore = input.indexOf("_", firstUnderscore + 1);
    if (secondUnderscore >= 0) {
        int thirdUnderscore = input.indexOf("_", secondUnderscore + 1);
        if (thirdUnderscore >= 0) output = input.substring(0, firstUnderscore + 1) + replacement + input.substring(thirdUnderscore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Stultuskes suggestion:

```
public static String replaceXthElement(String input, int x, String replacement) {
    String[] array = input.split("_");
    array[x] = replacement;
    
    return String.join("_", array);; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `String.join("_", array);` ?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad Socialized with Java7 ;)

Comment: @user16320675, thanks for the hints. Sure, in a real world scenario the length of the array should be checked. But I don't get the second point. What do you mean by "empty trailing entries"?

Comment: @user16320675, thank you for the clarification. Did not take this into account because of OPs description of the input.

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using Regex and replace method.
Assuming the String to be replaced has 4 digits followed by 1 char and 1 digit.

- `\\d{4}` matches exactly 4 digits.
- `\\D{1}` matches exactly 1 non-Digit.
- `\\d{1}` matches exactly 1 digit.
- Reluctant quantifier `(?)` can be used assuming the requirement is strict that the format must be "2020H1"
- Using `"("` will group the Regex in that sequence.

```
    String versionString = "alba_tango_2021H1_[ten]";
    String modifiedVersionString = versionString.replaceFirst("(\\d{4}?\\D{1}?\\d{1}?)","test");
    System.out.println(modifiedVersionString);
```

Output:

`alba_tango_test_[ten]`

You can find more info about regex here. [Regex Pattern API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Yes, May be I am incorrect here. But I believe the 2021H1 has to be removed. It looks like a standard versioning format to me.